# Java Script não altera uma div com display de "none" para "block"

Tags: javascript, div, display, style

Gostaria de uma ajuda sobre o element style.display no java script. O JS não esta alterando uma div declarada na jsp de none, para block. Tenho uma página jsp que tem uma div do tipo escondida:

```
<input type="radio" id="ContaForm" name="nuTipoContaR"  value="1" checked/>&nbsp;Conta raíz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" id="ContaForm" name="nuTipoContaE" value="2"/>&nbsp;Estrangeira&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br>
        </div>
    <div id="divInstituicao" style="display:none;">

                    <div id="divInstituicaoEstrangeira" style="display:none;">  
                        <div class="divlinha">
                            <div class="linhaLabel"> Instituição:</div>
                            <div class="divlinhaLabelTexto">
                                <html:text property="instituicaoEstrangeira" styleId="instituicaoEstrangeira" value="" onkeypress='return trataEnterAspas( event );' onblur="trataCaracteres( this );" onkeyup="trataCaracteres( this );" maxlength="60" size="78" /> <br />
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>  
         </div>
```

No javascript minha intenção é verificar se a div é none e se o radiobutton for clicado , exibir essa div. Mas não esta indo, ele até reconhece que a div é none , mas no **document.ElementById("instituicao").style.display="block"** o sistema não exibe a div na tela do jsp.
ME ajudem por favor, sou iniciante e já fiz algumas pesquisas, mas sem sucesso.

```
$('#form input:radio').bind("click", function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var tipoTce = $("input[@name='ContaForm']:checked").value;
            tipoConta = parseInt($(this).val());

            if(tipoConta == "2"){
                    var deConta = $("#deContaEstrangeira").val();
                    var nuContaEstranegira = $("#nuContaEstrangeira").val();
                    var noContaEstrangeira = $("#noContaEstrangeira").val();

                    document.getElementById("descMotivo").innerHTML = deMotConta;
                    document.getElementById("noTipoConta1").value = noContaEstrangeira;
                    document.getElementById("deTipoConta1").value = deMotConta;
                    document.getElementById("nuTipoConta1").value = nuContaEstrangeira;
                    if(document.getElementById("divInstituicao").style.display == "none"){
                    document.getElementById("divInstituicao").style.display = "block";
                    }
                }

            else if(tipoConta =="1"){
                    retornaTipoContaRaiz();
            }
    }});
```

Comment: No HTML tens `divInstituicaoEstrangeira` no JavaScript tens `document.getElementById("divInstituicao")`. São nomes diferentes... ou seja o conteúdo está com `display: none;` também.

Comment: Obrigada Sérgio, vou alterar aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está alterando o `display` apenas de 1 div que contém outra que também está oculta.

A solução é retirar o `style="display:none;"` da div interna `divInstituicaoEstrangeira` alterar apenas o display da *div-mãe* `divInstituicao`:

```
if(document.getElementById("divInstituicao").style.display == "none"){
 document.getElementById("divInstituicao").style.display = "block";
}
```

No entanto, como vejo que vc usa jQuery, sugiro aplicar o mesmo em seu código, ficando assim:

```
if($("#divInstituicao").not(":visible")){
    $("#divInstituicao").show();
}
```

> Não faz muito sentido vc carregar uma biblioteca jQuery na sua página
>   e usá-la parcialmente, misturando com JS puro, cujos códigos são mais
>   extensos e mais suscetíveis a erros.

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo alerta! Esta funcionando conforme gostaria. Esse js, está uma mistura só. Na verdade eu estou adicionando algumas verificações, pois esse arquivo já existia na minha empresa. Eu fico assim, sem saber qual notação eu uso nessa situação.

Answer (score 0):

No HTML tens `divInstituicao` e sua div filha `divInstituicaoEstrangeira`  ambas com `display: none;`

No JavaScript tens somente `document.getElementById("divInstituicao")`. Tens de ativar ambas:

```
document.getElementById("divInstituicao").style.display = "block";                  
document.getElementById("divInstituicaoEstrangeira").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Obrigada, vou alterar

Comment: Muito obrigada, eseta funcionando conforme eu gostaria, e esta exibindo o campo em tela agora. =D

Comment: @Priscila.pcs ótimo. Dei resposta também apesar de ter comentado na pergunta. Já agora, se tens JS nativo misturado com jQuery é melhor ir tirando o jQuery. jQuery está a desaparecer porque é uma tecnologia antiga. JavaScript vai sempre ficar igual.